# Is there a preprocessor instruction to make a XCode build fail?

Tags: ios, c, xcode, c-preprocessor

Is there a preprocessor instruction to make a XCode build fail? (or pragma_mark or something else)

For instance, I develop an application for 3 different environments including several web URL to fetch. So far I don't know the URL that will be used for the production environment and I want to insert an instruction in my code to prevent an anticipated build from running with this environment.

My code looks like

```
#ifdef ENV1
...
#endif

#ifdef ENV2
...
#endif

#ifdef ENV3
#some_instruction_that_prevent_success_build
...
#endif
```

In other words, I want an instruction that acts as a blocking TODO.

Comment: The #error works fine, but why does it need to be a preprocessor instruction? You could use `@@@ TODO` just as easily.

Comment: My 2 problems are that I want the project to compile and run for ENV1 and ENV2 and fail only for ENV3, and if the error message could be customized to one I've set rather than a generic error. For instance, using @@@ TODO, you'd get a "Parse Issue - Unexpected '@' in program"  that could frightened a client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error preprocessor directive is what you're after.

```
#error "Danger, Will Robinson!"
```

Comment: It works... but it seems to be just because it is an unknown preprocessor instruction. :) Any good online resource to recommend about all preprocessing instructions documentation?

Comment: I am absolutely certain that #error **is** a known preprocessor instruction - it's documented in the GCC C preprocessor  (http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cpp/cpp.html#SEC37).

Comment: @Dirty Henry: See what the compiler tells you when it sees this directive when trying to compile.

Comment: @Dirty Henry: `#error` is part of the C standard. (`#warning`, however, is not.) If you want a list of preprocessor directives, get a copy of K&R or a copy of the standard ( http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf )

Comment: When putting #error "Danger, Will Robinson!" inside my code, I get 3 errors "Lexical or preprocessor issue" (i guess 1 message per word). I'm not using gcc though but Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 (which may be the default for iOS projects as I've never changed this by hand).

Comment: `#error` is defined in section 6.10.5 of the 1999 ISO C standard.  It's also in the 1989 ANSI standard, so your compiler will support it unless it's *very* old (and if it's that old you've got other problems).  It has the advantage that a compiler is *not permitted* to succeed if a `#error` directive isn't skipped by `#if`, `#ifdef`, or `#ifndef`; for any other errors, the compiler can issue a warning and continue.

Comment: @lxt: Your conclusion is correct; your reasoning is not.  The GCC documentation doesn't define the language (unless the language you're talking about is GNU C).  `#warning`, for example, is a gcc extension.

Comment: Time to close the question. Thanks for all the messages. My conclusion is that even if the #error support by XCode 4.2 and Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 is not as nice as could be, it did the trick!